# Trying to see if data points fall within one of multiple date ranges on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, date, range

I have two tables, one with a series of events and the other with demographic information about the subjects of the events. The demographic data includes data ranges in which an subject was eligible for an events, and the event data contains a field with the date of the events. There are multiple date ranges for each subject as subjects frequently lose/regain eligibility. Some events fall outside the subject's eligibility period, and I am trying to add a column to the event table that shows a "0" if the event was in the eligibility period and a "1" if not.

Basically, my tables are like this:

```
            Events
     Subject  Date of Event
       A        1/1/2012
       A        3/4/2012
       B        2/2/2012
       B        3/4/2012

         Demographics
      Subject    Start         End
       A        1/1/2012    1/15/2012
       A        3/1/2012    3/31/2012
       B        2/1/2012    2/29/2012
       B        4/1/2012    4/30/2012
```

I run a simple CASE WHEN statement where if event date is before the start date or after the end date, return "0" else "1". And the result is:

```
  Subject    Date of Event       Start     End         Value
     A        1/1/2012         1/1/2012    1/15/2012      1
     A        1/1/2012         3/1/2012    3/31/2012      0
     A        3/4/2012         1/1/2012    1/15/2012      0
     A        3/4/2012         3/1/2012    3/31/2012      1
     B        2/2/2012         2/1/2012    2/29/2012      1
     B        2/2/2012         4/1/2012    4/30/2012      0
     B        3/4/2012         2/1/2012    2/29/2012      0
     B        3/4/2012         4/1/2012    4/30/2012      0
```

I can take these results and export them to Excel and then do a VLOOKUP with another event identifier that will give me the end result I need, but surely there's a way to do this in my SQL script? Is there any way to check the event date through multiple ranges before assigning it a value? Or to delete duplicate events at the end, but conditionally based on the value assigned?

EDIT:

My apologies, I did a poor job explaining my situation in the initial question. The second table I showed above are the results I am getting now, not my desired results. The problem I'm having is that in this dataset, a single subject can have several events and several different eligibility periods, and I need to check each event to see if it falls within any of those eligibility periods. It's a massive dataset, so I would prefer to get a single result for each event that tells me if it fell within any of the subject's eligibility windows. Currently, each event gets paired with each of the subject's eligibility periods, with a value of 1 if the event fell within the eligibility period it is paired with in that data point. So my ideal output would really be:

```
          Subject      Date of event     Value
             A            1/1/2012         1
             A            3/1/2012         1
             B            2/2/2012         1
             B            3/4/2012         0
```

And like I said, I can get this by using a VLOOKUP in Excel with the imperfect SQL results I'm getting now, but I imagine there's a way to get this in SQL.

Comment: Please provide the final result based on your data sample.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that for each subject/event, you want to know if the subject has demographics.  If so, then you want to do a `left join`:

```
select e.subject, e.eventdate, max(d.start) as start, max(d.end as end),
       (max(d.subject) is not null) as value       
from events e left join
     demographics d
     on s.subject = d.subject and
        e.eventdate between d.start and d.end
group by e.subject, e.eventdate;
```

Comment: I don't recall why I asked this question a decade ago but I think the key part I was missing in my first days using SQL was that I wanted to take the max 1/0, yes/no value for each event. Very belated thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
SELECT e.subject, e.date, d.start, d.end, 
       (e.date BETWEEN d.start AND d.end) value
  FROM events e JOIN demographics d
    ON e.subject = d.subject
```

Output:

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| subject | date       | start      | end        | value |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| A       | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-15 |     1 |
| A       | 2012-03-04 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-15 |     0 |
| A       | 2012-01-01 | 2012-03-01 | 2012-03-31 |     0 |
| A       | 2012-03-04 | 2012-03-01 | 2012-03-31 |     1 |
| B       | 2012-02-02 | 2012-02-01 | 2012-02-29 |     1 |
| B       | 2012-03-04 | 2012-02-01 | 2012-02-29 |     0 |
| B       | 2012-02-02 | 2012-04-01 | 2012-04-30 |     0 |
| B       | 2012-03-04 | 2012-04-01 | 2012-04-30 |     0 |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6d99a/2)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: This is what I was doing before, I've clarified the question so my desired outcomes are more clear. Thanks for your help

Comment: To be precise, the first answer is exactly what I'm doing.